# unity.mvc4: how to get a reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I've setup Unity in Bootstrapper.cs of my MVC application, all is working well for constructor injection on my controllers...

My question is when I'm in an ActionResult within a controller I need to get a reference to the container I previously created in Bootstrapper.cs so I can use it to resolve classes for me.

e.g:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //-- container needs a reference to unity container
    var testService = container.Resolve<ITestService>();
    return View(testService);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I need to get a reference to the container

No you don't. You [should never need to reference the container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) (or the `DependencyResolver`) from within your application.

Use constructor injection instead:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITestService testService;

    // constructor
    public HomeController(ITestService testService)
    {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(this.testService);
    }
}
```

Since you are using the MVC3 integration package for unity, you probably registered a Unity specific `DependencyResolver` in the startup path of your application. That looks much like this:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

When you've done this, your custom `DependencyResolver` will delegate the creation of controllers to the Unity container and the Unity container is able to inject depdencies of the constructor's of the controllers.

The next thing you should never do is letting views do any work and making them dependent on your services. Views should be dumb and do nothing more than map the data they get from the controller and transform them to HTML (or JSON or whatever).

In other words, do not pass on the `testService` to the view. Calling the `testService` from within the view hides that logic, makes the view more complicated, and makes the system hard to test. Since you're using an `ITestService` abstraction, I assume you want to be able to test your code, but testing the view is not easy (or at least, not as easy as you can test the controller).

What you should do is let the controller call the `testService` and gather the data that is needed for the view to use. Than pass on that data (perhaps combined in a single class, a view model) to the view.